# An RNN that takes multiple (inconsistent sized) rows from a CSV file as a single input

Tags: python, csv, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have extracted facial features from several videos in the form of facial action units(AU) using openface. These features span for several seconds and hence take several rows in a CSV file (each row containing AU data for each frame of the video). Originally, I had multiple CSV files as input for an NN but, as advised by other people (elsewhere), I have concatenated and condensed the data into a single file. My CSV columns look like this:

**Note: Row is NOT in my data but just here to represent how its shown in a CSV file**

```
Row | Filename | Label | the other columns contain AU related data/vectors
1   | 0        |  Yes  | ...
2   | 0        |  Yes  | ...
.
.
.
197 | 0        |  Yes  | ...
198 | 0        |  Yes  | ...
199 | 1        |  No   | ...
199 | 1        |  No   | ...
.
.
.
509 | 1        |  No   | ...
510 | 1        |  No   | ...
511 | 2        |  No   | ...
512 | 2        |  No   | ...
.
.
.
And so on
```

Filename contains individual "ID" that helps keep track of a single "example" as each example consists of multiple rows BUT the number of rows that each example have is always different from one another. The label column contains 2 possible values. Either "yes" or "no".

The most likely scenario is that I will require some form of a RNN but been unable to find any code that can help me out in this scenario. Can someone please help me out? I have no idea how/where to move forward.